# Where can I find a graph of the current size of mining pools?

Tags: mining-pools, charts

Where can I find a graph of the estimated size of each mining pool relative to the overall hashrate of the entire bitcoin network?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The http://bitcoinwatch.com/ site gives a pie-chart of the hasrate distribution by mining pool.

Comment: This answer is outdated. Bitcoinwatch doesn't show a mining pool chart anymore.

Answer (score 5):

Hashrate distribution An estimation of hashrate distribution amongst the largest mining pools

- http://blockchain.info/pools

Answer (score 0):

Time for an update! At the moment, the following sites feature charts about the distribution of mining pools:

- [Bitcoinity](https://data.bitcoinity.org/bitcoin/hashrate/) (hash rate)
- [Blockchain.info](https://blockchain.info/pools) (number of blocks mined)
- [Blocktrail](https://www.blocktrail.com/BTC/pools) (number of blocks mined)
- [Coin Dance](https://coin.dance/blocks) (number of blocks mined, including support for proposals)

*Disclaimer: I didn't check the accuracy of the data, and a pool's hash rate will vary over time. The number of blocks mined will vary randomly, of course.*